# just everything together for a number

Tags: php, mysqli

I should have made ​​such that it is +1 up ​​database instance every time you write a status on its away

problem: right now when writing +1 then the whole time 1

solved: this is how I want when I have 1 point in advance so it must just above the old numbers thus making it for 2 and 3, etc.

```
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('UPDATE bruger SET point=? WHERE id=?')) {
$stmt->bind_param('si', $point, $id);
$point =  +1;
$id = $_SESSION["id"];
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: Try `UPDATE bruger SET point=point+1 WHERE id=?` ?

Comment: @andrewsi Easy!.. Want to do an answer so you can get some points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should either do a select query first, then add 1 using PHP and then do an update query, or change the update query so that it automatically adds 1 without using PHP, which is better.

Changing the query would result in the following code:

```
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('UPDATE bruger SET point=point + 1 WHERE id=?')) {
  $stmt->bind_param('si', $id);
  $id = $_SESSION["id"];
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help :) i will like its so fast i'am can :)